# Alternatives to WebEx?

Tags: webapp-rec

Other than using Skype's screen-sharing tool (which is not a webapp), how can I share my desktop with remote users?

I know some appliances exist that do this through a web interface (Juniper has one), but they're more expensive than a home user can really afford.

What other tools exist in this space, especially in the "webapp" category?

Comment: https://www.uberconference.com is a good option.

Answer (score 8):

Awesome and Free (for non-commercial use). (You can't beat that combination.)

[TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com)

Answer (score 4):

[Joel Spolsky's](http://joelonsoftware.com) company [Fog Creek Software](http://fogcreek.com) offers their "[Copilot](https://www.copilot.com/)" web app type service that launches very quickly and easily and doesn't require any installation or setup on either end. For only $5, the day passes are very cost effective to use at a moment's notice.

Comment: I've used this a few times. It is no frills, but it is also almost zero-complexity. It just works, no big whoop. 

Exactly what I want when trying to give tech support to a tech-illiterate family member who doesn't know the difference between RAM memory and HD memory.

Answer (score 2):

We use GoToMeeting, which we like a lot. There is also SharedView (https://connect.microsoft.com/site94?wa=wsignin1.0) which is free.

Aslo, Scott Mitchell penned a [nice comparison recently](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2010/07/18/a-review-of-desktop-screen-sharing-software.aspx).

Comment: I wasn't aware of TeamViewer, suggested by another user here, I will definitely look into it. Note, however, that it is only free for non-commercial use, and quite pricey otherwise.

Comment: The non-commercial use is important. I updated my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Try [DimDim](http://dimdim.com), it is the best! (start for free)

Comment: DimDim got bought by Salesforce. :-(

Comment: This service is dead. The website is not even active anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe ConnectNow](http://www.adobe.com/acom/connectnow/) is free for up to 3 users

Comment: Adobe ConnectNow works really well

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about [LogMeIn](http://www.logmein.com/) , ... which is free for non-commercial use; they also offer free noncom VPN software too which may be of help depending on your needs.

Comment: Further to eidylon's answer, [LogMeIn Express](https://secure.logmein.com/US/products/express/Default.aspx) currently offers view-only free screen sharing without installing the LogMeIn client.

Answer (score 0):

I've always liked [WebHuddle](https://www.webhuddle.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Mikogo](http://www.mikogo.com/) - it's free and awesome.

Answer (score 0):

We've had great success with [Zoho Meeting](http://www.zoho.com/meeting/)